# Add textblock dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, xamlreader

My code belows throw a null reference exception

[image]

```
    // Create a string
    String sb = "<TextBlock xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' Text=\"Name (as per IC)\" Margin=\"1,0,0,80\" Grid.RowSpan=\"2\"/>";

    // Create a textblock using a XamlReader
    TextBlock myTextBlock = (TextBlock)XamlReader.Load(sb.ToString());

    // Add created button to previously created container.
    splMain.Children.Add(myTextBlock);
```

Comment: Why is a simple new of a textblock not good enough for you ?

Comment: What item *exactly* is null? Is it `splMain`, or `splMain.Children`?

Comment: Because I want to read XAML mark up from file and then create a UI based on the file. Is there any solution? Thanks.

Comment: I found that myTextBlock is null. So I suspected I failed to create a textblock using a XAMLReader.load()

Comment: @TexanLee: I doubt, that the cause of NRE is `myTextBlock`. Post stack trace, please.

Comment: @Dennis ya. myTextBlock is null when run